# Selenium (Java) - getting list ids based on other attribute

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've got a html snippet like this:

```
<div class="hb-felt">
   <ul class="hb-feltlist">
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
        <input class="hb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
         disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" 
         id="refusalTooExpensive">
        <label class="hb-label" for="refusalTooExpensive">Too 
         expensive
        </label>
      </li>
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
         <input class="hb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
          disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" 
          id="refusalInvalid">
         <label class="hb-label" for="refusalInvalid">Invalid</label>
      </li>
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
         <input class="hb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
          disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" 
          id="refusalEconomy">
         <label class="hb-label" for="refusalEconomy">Economy-related 
          refusal</label>
      </li>
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
         <input class="hb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
          disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" 
          id="refusalLackingPrimaryFunds">
         <label class="hb-label" for="refusalLackingPrimaryFunds">Lacking 
          primary funds</label>
      </li>
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
         <input class="hb-checkbox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" 
          disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" 
          id="refusalSecondaryFunds">
         <label class="hb-label" for="refusalSecondaryFunds">Lacking 
          secondary funds</label>
      </li>
      <li data-selector="refusal_alt" class="ng-star-inserted">
         <input class="hb-checkbox ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" 
          disableelementilesemodus="" type="checkbox" id="refusalOther">
         <label class="hb-label" for="refusalOther">Other</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, each list element includes the tag `data-selector="refusal_alt"`. This is identical for all elements.

This is a dynamically created list, and the id-tag and the label text will differ (but the data-selector will allways be the same).

What's the best way for Selenium to go through this and make a list of all the id tags or the label text?

Comment: it's a shot in the dark, but try `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li[data-selector='refusal_alt']"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should select all `label` elements that have a `li` parent element with the `data-selector` attribute set to `refusal_alt`. Afterwards you iterate over the matched elements and for each matched element, you determine it's text and put the result in the resulting list:

```
List<WebElement> matchedElements = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-selector='refusal_alt'] > label"));
List<String> labels = matchedElements.stream().map(element -> element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even shorter (labels):

```
List<String> labels = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-selector='refusal_alt'] > label")).stream().map(element->element.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(ids):

```
List<String> ids= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[data-selector='refusal_alt'] > label")).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("for")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         WebElement ul=driver.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
        List<WebElement>lis=ul.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

        for(WebElement li:lis)
        {
            WebElement label=li.findElement(By.tagName("label"));

            String id=label.getAttribute("for");
            //every li is creating attribute for and that's your id for that 
             particular input field
            li.findElement(By.id(id));
        }
```